# ViewPager tabs - use ActionBar tab style when ViewPager is not first element?

Tags: android

I want to use a ViewPager with tabs. However, I need to place a TextView above the pager (and thus tabs) like so:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
  <TextView /> /** Need to have the textview here. **/
  <ViewPager />
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like for the tab widget, we could use PagerTitleStrip or PagerTabStrip to get a tab widget inline:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
  <TextView />
  <ViewPager>
    <PagerTitleStrip />
  </ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

but the PagerTitleStrip and PagerTabStrip widgets have a different style than what you'd find if you just used ActionBar tabs. I would like the tabs to look like them, having evenly spaced tab sizes.

Is there another tab widget you can pair with a ViewPager, or are these the only options? I'm referring to this document:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="48dip" />
```

and set `pstsShouldExpand` to true.

> If set to true, each tab is given the same weight, default false

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you. I hope the android team considers adding this feature to the stock widget someday.